# presentation about software archtitecture

Tags: android, java, presentation

I am doing a internship in software development and have to make a presentation about my work.

I was wondering are there any open source software for presenting software architecture?

Comment: *software architecture* cannot be displayed/presented. Data can. What kind of data do you want to present, how, on what hardware, to who, what OS, what can it cost, etc etc [Edit] your question

Answer (score 1):

I use [Gliffy](https://www.gliffy.com/) whenever I'm presenting software structure or code logic. It's a pretty zippy, cross-platform way to build flowcharts, OOP models, and other types of modeling.

Exports to image formats so you can shove them in whatever document you like. Also integrates with Confluence, if you're in need of that kind of thing.